# How to delay Silverlight's loading screen?

Tags: c#, silverlight, load

I have an experimental project in silverlight, that has no database and scarce resources. Now, I wanted to know if you can prolong or delay the Silverlight loading screen, so I can check what I have modified in the loading page. Problem is, it loads too fast for me to check. I have no data to fetch from the webservice or any resources needed. I'm just experimenting in modifying Silverlight's load page. Can this be done code-wise? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite following the question. What is it that you "have modified in the loading page"? And why would making the loading page show up longer help you check it?

Comment: I don't know how to modify the loading page (the xaml which is displayed while the .xap downloads).   Do you think you could provide us with some code to help understand the issue?

Comment: @BPerreault he is not providing tutorial he is asking dude... Ken Smit He must be modifying he's splash screen aka(Silverlight Default Loading Page)

Comment: @AllanChua (dude?) So is this question about modifying a .xaml page( how is that modified on the fly) or is it about inserting javascript into the load process before the .xaml which is default loading screen is processed.  That is what I'm asking.

Comment: @BPerreault I think you're lost try to read this so that you could have idea http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903962(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks, @AllanChua I hope I can help you out the same someday.

Comment: @BPerreault No Problem at all buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already found the answer. I just needed a timer for things. thanks for all the queries, anyway

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
EventHandler eh = null;

eh = (s, args) =>
{
    timer.Stop();
    this.RootVisual = new Test();
    timer.Tick -= eh;
};

timer.Tick += eh;

timer.Start();
}
```